# Substring operations in windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, substring

I have a requirement for batch script where I need to retrieve numbers mentioned in brackets.

Example `-abc(12349)`

The output should be `12349`.

Comment: I suspect that if you knew the correct terms to look for, you'd be able to find a solution yourself. In this case, you're going to need to use the brackets as _delimiters_ and process the string with a _for loop_, then extract the _token_ that contains the string you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If your input strings will only ever contain the one set of parentheses, a `for /f` loop using `()` as delims and capturing the `2`nd token will suffice:

```bat
:# commandline example. double % characters for use in a batch file
 For /f "tokens=2 Delims=()" %G in ("-abc(12349)")Do Echo(%G
```

However, if your input strings may contain multiple sets of parentheses or false positives (parentheses containing undesired data), regex is the better option for ensuring the content extracted is what is desired. Batch doesn't support complex regex patterns innately, however can leverage powershell to do so. (of course, you could most likely do whatever set of tasks you are doing entirely in powershell)

an example:

```bat
@Echo off

 Set "RegexArgs="^.*?[-][a-z]{0,3}\(" "\).*?$" "\d+""

 Call :Extract %RegexArgs% rVar1 "-abc(12349)"
 Call :Extract %RegexArgs% rVar2 "hello(0) -def(42)"
 Call :Extract %RegexArgs% rVar3 "false -tis(notnumbers)"
 Call :Extract %RegexArgs% rVar4 "false -istoolong(0)"

 Set rVar

Goto :Eof

:Extract <Regex:Prefix> <Regex:Suffix> <Regex:Target> <ReturnVar> <String>
:# Regex patterns recieved as args are not validated. See below link for regex syntax.
:# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1
 If "%~5" == "" Exit /b 1
 Set "Prefix=%~1"
 Set "Suffix=%~2"
 Set "Target=%~3"
 Set "String=%~5"
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 Set "String=!String:^^=^!"
 Set "Prefix=!Prefix:^^=^!"
 Set "Suffix=!Suffix:^^=^!"
 Set "Target=!Target:^^=^!"

 For /f "usebackq Delims=" %%G in (`
 powershell -nologo -noprofile -c ^
 "If('!String!' -match '!Prefix!!Target!!Suffix!$') {$String = $('!String!' -replace '!Prefix!' -replace '!Suffix!');write-host "$String"}"
 `)Do Endlocal & Set "%4=%%G"

Goto :Eof
```

Expected output:

```bat
rVar1=12349
rVar2=42
```